# getelementbyid in firefox onclick display:block script troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have a script which toggles block/none display of a div, onClick. The onClick also toggles an associated "thumbnail" image from active to inactive.

Only in Firefox, the div's stack on top of each other. It seems as if the onClick is not associating the display:none style with the current item.

I made sure that all divs have associated ID's which seems to be the top questions related to getElementById issues in Firefox.

Any thoughts on troubleshooting this would be helpful, thank you!

Here is my javascript:

```
var curVid = "VideoA";
var curImg = "VideoA_thumbnail";

function changeVideo(id, img)
  {
   if(document.getElementById(id) != null && curVid != id)
  {

    document.getElementById(curVid).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(id + "_thumb").src = "..//Thumbnails//" + img + "_selected.jpg";
    document.getElementById(id + "_thumb").style.cursor = "default";
    document.getElementById(curVid + "_thumb").src = "..//Thumbnails//" + curImg + ".jpg";
    document.getElementById(curVid + "_thumb").style.cursor = "pointer";

    if(VideoJS.browserSupportsVideo())
      {
        document.getElementById(curVid + "_video").pause();
        document.getElementById(curVid + "_video").currentTime = 0;
        VideoJS.setup(id + "_video");
        document.getElementById(id + "_video").play();
      }
    else
      {
        $f(curVid + "_flash").stop();
        $f(id + "_flash").play();
      }

curVid = id;
curImg = img;
}
}
```

and this is the HTML

```
<div id = "VideoA" style = "display:block;">content here</div> 
<div id = "VideoB" style = "display:none;">content here</div> 
<div id = "VideoC" style = "display:none;">content here</div> 
<div id = "VideoD" style = "display:none;">content here</div> 
<div id = "VideoE" style = "display:none;">content here</div> 



<div>
   <img src = "a.jpg" id = "VideoA_thumb" onclick = "changeVideo('VideoA', 'VideoA_thumb')" />
   <img src = "b.jpg" id = "VideoB_thumb" onclick = "changeVideo('VideoB', 'VideoB_thumb')" />
   <img src = "c.jpg" id = "VideoC_thumb" onclick = "changeVideo('VideoC', 'VideoC_thumb')" />
   <img src = "d.jpg" id = "VideoD_thumb" onclick = "changeVideo('VideoD', 'VideoD_thumb')" />
   <img src = "e.jpg" id = "VideoE_thumb" onclick = "changeVideo('VideoE', 'VideoE_thumb')" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML has `_thumbnail` but the JS has `_thumb`. I don't see how it would work correctly in any browser.

Comment: P.S. It would be nice if you indented your code to make it readable.

Comment: Sorry about that, I indented code for readability. And when I was trying to simplify the code, I forgot to update the word "thumbnail" to "thumb". But that is fixed now. Thanks for the input Barmar, first time poster here!

Comment: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDpmv/1/) using buttons instead of images, and no videoJS stuff, and it works properly.

Comment: Happening to me in Safari, too. And I was seeing it in my fiddle when I had the videoJS code there.

Comment: I'm getting an error `INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.` on the `.currentTime = 0;` line, so it never gets to the statement that updates `curVid`.